# How to count rows of a column and use if condition for counting lower than 2 row to run specific code in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to set an if condition that if the referrer_id column counts less than 2 rows with where clause of referrer_id,

I have tried this code but the code under if condition is still runs while the the result becomes with more than 2 rows.

```
$countU = User::where('referrer_id', $ref_id)->get();
        //$PaidStatus = User::where('paid_status', '1');

        if($countU->count() <= 2){

        $new = $ref_user['earning'] = $ref_user['earning'] + $percentage;
        $new_ball = $ref_user['balance'];
        $ref_user->save();
      }
```

Please let me know where I am wrong.

Comment: Change your if condition to something like `if($countU->count() < 2){ //do the stuff }` try this because your id condition checks if it is less than or equal to two while mine will check if it is less than two then do the stuff else ignore

Comment: yea, solved this thanks man. I have one more issue, please answere this. I want to get all records from a table with two where  clause and then I want to call the columns in the variables from returned result. this is the query:-            $user_match = MemberExtra::where('left_bv', '>=', 1)->where('right_bv', '>=', 1);
                    
                    $user1 = $user_match->user_id;
                    $ref_id = $user1->referrer_id;
                    $ref_user = User::find($ref_id);

Comment: i'm posting it as answer please accept and up vote and also please post your other issue as a question so others will also get help if i or some one else answers you..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should use **count()** method like this :

```
$countU = User::where('referrer_id', $ref_id)->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your if condition to something like:

```
if($countU->count() < 2)
{
   $new = $ref_user['earning'] = $ref_user['earning'] + $percentage;
   $new_ball = $ref_user['balance'];
   $ref_user->save();
}
```

try the above condition because your `if` condition checks if it is `less than or equal to two` while mine will check if it is `less than two` then do the stuff else ignore

Thanks.